# How can I make a list of only specific items of an API JSON file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have a body of data in a JSON file from an API GET request, but I can't figure out how to get only the specific items I need from it.

I have Visual Studio Code installed, is there a way to do this in it?

Comment: what is piece of code, which programming language, will you be able share that portion of the code

Comment: So the JSON file contains data like this:
"body": "",
                "sent_at_utc": "",
                "operator_id": ,
                "from": "",
                "sent_at": "",
                "url": "",
                "name": "",
                "operator_name": "",
                "sent_at_timezone": "",
                "sent_at_time": "",
                "type": 
                "display_name": "

I redacted the information in it, cause it's sensitive. So basically, I have 39000 lines of data like this in the file and I'd like to get only the "url" info from all of this.

Comment: what is the programming language, C#?, JavaScript?, Java? which one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question. As I understood, you send a request to an endpoint and receive a JSON object.

  You can check the documentation of the API you're using. It can have other endpoints or query parameters that return the data you're looking for. In any case, you can filter the data yourself with the help of a programming language.

  If you be more specific with the language and API you're using; JSON you receive and the desired result, you can get a better response.